# Integrate Simple Injector into MVC 5 site that also has some Web Api 2 controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project, using the default template which uses ASP.NET Identity 2. You know, the one with that awful poor's man dependency injection using `OwinContext` and the `AccountController`.

I've successfully been able to integrate SI 4.3.0 into the project by following [this example](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/597). It shows and old syntax, but with a few changes, it worked.
I'm now happily injecting dependencies into `AccountController` and I'm able to write tests for it easily.

The problem is that I also have a few Web Api 2 controllers in the same MVC project and I'm not sure how should I integrate SI for it to work.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
  {
    // This ApiDependencyResolver is a custom class and as you can see, 
    // it's being "injected" a value from a static method. Awful. I want to replace this with SI.
    config.DependencyResolver = new ApiDependencyResolver(DataAccessLayerFactory.GetInstance());

    // Use a custom JSON formatter as well so that requests from
    // the browser are returned as properly formatted JSON by default.
    config.Formatters.Add(new ApiJsonFormatter());

    // Set up the Web API routes.
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: ApiPrefix + "/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
  }
}
```

The method above is called in `Application_Start` from `Global_asax` using `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);`.
But my container setup is done in `Startup.cs` (marked with `OwinStartup` attribute).

I already have a registration for the DataAccessLayer, and it works well for MVC controllers. But as soon as I hit an action of an API controller that needs it, I get a response saying `An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'TenantsController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.`

How can I integrate SI into an MVC5 project with some Api Controllers?

Comment: Did you read the [Web API integration guide](https://simpleinjector.org/webapi)? And if so, what questions remain after reading that guide?

Comment: Could you provide more info what is the problem? Not sure how SI works with full framework but have you tried adding parameterless constructor? The error says `Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor`.

Answer (score 0):

So the documentation doesn't explicit say how to do this, but combining both MVC and WebApi approaches seems to do the trick.

So the important part is that we need to set both dependency resolvers by doing:

```
// MVC
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));

// Web Api
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
   new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

And also we need to register both MVC and WebApi controllers by doing:

```
container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```